# Add axis to PIL image

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

Is there a way to save large (4000000, 200, 3) numpy RGB array as an image with axis using PIL? Or maybe any other packages?
I tried use matplotlib but it has weak savefig method whic not allow me to save large figures
So then I try use PIL and it works ok but not allow me to add axis to the image

Comment: What file format are you hoping to save a 4million pixel tall image in? What do you mean by *"add an axis to it"*? Will the result be (4000000,200,3,1)?

Comment: No ideas for appropriated format, eps will be good choice I guess.
Furthermore, I already can save such large figure in high quality. Question here is how to add an axis to this image : axis X, Y,  where X - image width and Y is height, not new dimension in array as you assumed